# Convert Local Time {'09:58:00'} to UTC

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datetime-format, sql-date-functions

I have a requirement to store Local time(10:31:00) to UTC(04:31:09) in the SQL Server.

I have used the below query to get the desired result.
I have combined `@VitalReadingDate='2024-01-11'` and local time (10:31:00) to get UTC Time (04:31:09), but it returns Local time not converting in UTC

```
CONVERT(datetime2, 
    CONVERT(varchar, @VitalReadingDate) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, @VitalReadingTime)
) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
```

Comment: If you are using SQLSERVER 2016 and above check this https://sqlkover.com/converting-a-datetime-to-utc/ . You should specify the Timezone of the local time too, only then can conversion happen from local to UTC, else by default the timezone is considered UTC.

Comment: Side note you should always specify the length of a varchar

Comment: Also be aware that the timezone conversions are date-dependent in areas with daylight-savings or summer time. There will also be discontinuities at the "spring forward" and "fall back" transitions.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, you need to also specify your local time zone if you want to convert between time zones.
I know the syntax looks a bit silly but I didn't write the rules - so it's something like this:

```
select SYSDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'Your local time zone' AT TIME ZONE 'Target Time Zone';
```

To get a list of time zone names you can query the system table called `time_zone_info`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.time_zone_info;
```

which will give you a list like this (very partial):

| name | current_utc_offset | is_currently_dst |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Cape Verde Standard Time | -01:00 | 0 |
| UTC | +00:00 | 0 |
| GMT Standard Time | +00:00 | 0 |
| Greenwich Standard Time | +00:00 | 0 |
| Sao Tome Standard Time | +00:00 | 0 |
| Morocco Standard Time | +01:00 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Also, Based on your code I'm assuming `@VitalReadingDate` and `@VitalReadingTime` are variables of types `Date` and `Time` respectively - so you should be aware there's a better way to combine them to a `DateTime2` value - which is to convert them to their binary values, combine these values and then convert that to `DateTime2`:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME2, CONVERT(VARBINARY(6),TimeValue) + CONVERT(BINARY(3),DateValue))
```

Please note that the order here is critical. The `+` operator here is concatenation, not addition, so if you do the date before the time you'll get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

For more information, read Jeff Moden's [Combine DATE and TIME to DATETIME2 in SQL Server](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server) article on SQLServerCentral.

To some up - here's a complete example:

```
DECLARE @VitalReadingDate Date = '2024-01-11',
        @VitalReadingTime Time = '10:31:00';

SELECT @VitalReadingDate As DateValue
     , @VitalReadingTime As TimeValue
     , CONVERT(DATETIME2, CONVERT(VARBINARY(6),@VitalReadingTime) + CONVERT(BINARY(3),@VitalReadingDate)) As LocalDateTime
     , CONVERT(DATETIME2, CONVERT(VARBINARY(6),@VitalReadingTime) + CONVERT(BINARY(3),@VitalReadingDate))
         AT TIME ZONE 'Central Asia Standard Time' -- assumed* 
         AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' As UTC;
```

Which results in this:

| DateValue | TimeValue | LocalDateTime | UTC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-11 | 10:31:00.0000000 | 2024-01-11 10:31:00.0000000 | 2024-01-11 04:31:00.0000000 +00:00 |

*I've based my assumption of your local time zone based on the 6 hours difference from UTC

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/XATCkXq9)